# Get the data back on the prevoius window when click on Back button

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have an application coded in C# and in the first window I enter some details in textboxes, combo boxes, radio buttons and a checkbox. When I click on the Next button, it goes to the second window and to do that, I use:

```
form2 f2 = new form2();
f2.show();
this.hide();
```

in that 2nd window, I have a Back button, which when clicked, goes to first window. To do that I use the code:

```
form1 f1 = new form1();
f1.show();
this.hide();
```

but the thing is, when I go to that window I lose all the data I entered. Is there an easy way to get this data back in to relevent controls without setting them one by one again?

Comment: I am assuming you are talking about winforms and not WPF, can you confirm?

Comment: `form2 f1 = new form1();`? Really? This compiles?

Comment: It's Winforms. Sorry..that was a mistake. It should be form1 f1 = new form1();
f1.show();
this.hide();

Comment: Simply don't create a new instance of `Form1`, keep the original instance by sending it to the 2nd form, by `new Form2(this)` or something like it.

Comment: how to use the form1 instance passes using Form2(this) from the 2nd form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider for the first form, when you want to show the second form

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
 Form2 frm;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frm = new Form2(this);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.Hide();
        frm.Show();
    }
```

now for second form

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Form1 frm;
        public Form2(Form1 fr)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            frm = fr;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            frm.Show();

        }

       }
    }
```

Comment: This is bad practice - you have now coupled the forms to each other.

Comment: @ oded, i know, but aroshlakshan was not getting your point. Thats why i provided a simple(according to you a bad practice) example.

Comment: @jailed abroad, this code works fine but when i click on back button and go to the 1st form the data is still there. But when i click the next button to go to the 2nd form, the data i entered previously are gone. Is there anyway to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating a new instance of Form1:

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
f1.Show();
this.Hide();
```

You need to keep the reference somehow (for example passing form1 as parameter to the constructor of Form2) and then calling - from Form2:

```
 public class Form2 {
       private Form1 nextWindow=null;
       public Form2(Form1 form1) {
            nextWindow=form1;
       }
 }
```

And somewhere in your code in Form2...

```
 nextWindow.Show();
 this.Hide(); //Form2
```

Comment: Events are probably a better choice, avoiding the coupling of the two windows to each other.

Comment: Can you please elaborate guys, i did not understand. Sorry!!

Comment: @aroshlakshan I've updated my answer. I hope is more clear now.

Comment: I created a class file and implemented your code but i couldn't create the code in form2. nextWindow cannnot be accessed from form2. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

When you do `form1 f1 = new form1();`, you are creating a *new* instance of `form1`, and will be showing the *new* instance, not the existing one.

Your `form2` should raise an event that `form1` subscribes to and which gets fired when the back button is clicked. The event handler on `form1` would call `this.Show()`.